# facebbok sdk Integrate interactive map in a post like Foursquare

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, bing-maps

I saw that when I publish to Facebook from Foursquare then you can click on the static image of the map and opens a window in Facebook with interactive map. (btw, bing logo showing on the interactive map)
how can i achieve that?

this is the post:

[image: the post]

this is after clicking the map:
[image: after clicking the map]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Simple Feed**

To publish a location you can use the `place` parameter in the [`/user-id/feed`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/feed#readfields) API. The `place` parameter be the **page-id** of that place.

For eg: If I want to publish a location: [Gurgaon](http://facebook.com/106487939387579)-

```
\POST /me/feed
place: 106487939387579
```

and the post will look like:

[image]

Earlier you were also able to use this with the `coordinates` parameter that include `longitude` and `latitude` but this is now deprecated. For this you have to use the [Open Graph](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/) Story- the same that **Foursquare** is using. That makes the story beautiful and more interactive. *"{user} checked in {action} at {place} on {AppName}"*

**Open Graph Story**

[Here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/using-actions#places) is explained how to tag places using the Open Graph Actions. (search for *Tagging places* in the link).

In you meta tags you have to set the location as-

```
<meta property="place:location:latitude"  content="37.416382"> 
<meta property="place:location:longitude" content="-122.152659">
```

---

(Note: The popup dialog that appears after clicking on the image is default be facebook, whenever a place is published. So don't worry about that)

Hope it helps. Good luck!