# Set the coordinate parameter for facebook graph checkins

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am implementing the Checkins Facebook Graph API using Facebook SDK. This is the code for Checkins

```
NSDictionary *dict=[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:accsstoken,@"access_token",@"253651184683030",@"place",@"I m here in this place",@"message",@"30.893075018178,75.821777459326",@"coordinates", nil];

        [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"/me/checkins"
                                     parameters:dict
                                     HTTPMethod:@"POST"
                              completionHandler:^(
                                                  FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                                  id result,
                                                  NSError *error
                                                  ) {
                                  NSLog(@"Error...%@",error);

                              }];
```

When I tried this above code. It gives me following error:

```
error =         {
            code = 160;
            message = "(#160) Invalid coordinates.  Coordinates must contain at least latitude and longitude.";
            type = OAuthException;
        };
```

It gives the coordinates issue. Is there a different way to pass the coordinates parameters? Please help me out of this issue.

Comment: possible duplicate of [facebbok sdk Integrate interactive map in a post like Foursquare](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22706323/facebbok-sdk-integrate-interactive-map-in-a-post-like-foursquare)

Comment: Publishing `checkins` is deprecated. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/checkin#publishing

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know checkins are deprecated and you should use post with place parameter.

And here is the link. [Facebook SDK reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/graph#postingobjects)

Edit: For people who too lazy to check the link, there is the sample code from Facebook.

```
// Create an object
NSMutableDictionary<FBOpenGraphObject> *restaurant = [FBGraphObject openGraphObjectForPost];

// specify that this Open Graph object will be posted to Facebook
restaurant.provisionedForPost = YES;

// Add the standard object properties
restaurant[@"og"] = @{ @"title":@"Restaurant Name", @"type":@"restaurant.restaurant", @"description":@"a description", @"image":image };

// Add the properties restaurant inherits from place
restaurant[@"place"] = @{ @"location" : @{ @"longitude": @"-58.381667", @"latitude":@"-34.603333"} };

// Add the properties particular to the type restaurant.restaurant
restaurant[@"restaurant"] = @{@"category": @[@"Mexican"],
                         @"contact_info": @{@"street_address": @"123 Some st",
                                            @"locality": @"Menlo Park",
                                            @"region": @"CA",
                                            @"phone_number": @"555-555-555",
                                            @"website": @"http://www.example.com"}};

// Make the Graph API request to post the object
FBRequest *request = [FBRequest requestForPostWithGraphPath:@"me/objects/restaurant.restaurant"
                                                graphObject:@{@"object":restaurant}];
[request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
  if (!error) {
    // Sucess! Include your code to handle the results here
    NSLog(@"result: %@", result);
    _objectID = [result objectForKey:@"id"];
    alertTitle = @"Object successfully created";
    alertText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"An object with id %@ has been created", _objectID];
    [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:alertTitle
                                message:alertText
                               delegate:self
                      cancelButtonTitle:@"OK!"
                      otherButtonTitles:nil] show];
  } else {
    // An error occurred, we need to handle the error
    // See: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/errors   
  }
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

Checkins have been deprecated in favor of attaching place information to posts, or tagging places in Open Graph stories.

You can refer here

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/checkins/