# How to post checkin on Facebook?

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-checkins

I need to checkin on Facebook, without using the default checkin option that comes with Facebook iOS SDK, because I need to filter the Facebook places, so that user can only checkin using places I filtered.
I have tried this using Facebook graph api.

```
NSDictionary *dict=[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:accsstoken,@"access_token",@"253651184683030",@"place",@"I m here in this place",@"message",@"30.893075018178,75.821777459326",@"coordinates", nil];

[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"/me/checkins"
                             parameters:dict
                             HTTPMethod:@"POST"
                      completionHandler:^(
                                          FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                          id result,
                                          NSError *error
                                          ) {
                          NSLog(@"Error...%@",error);

                         }];
```

if anybody know about this, Do let me know ? 
Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working code:

_place.facebookId = place id of location to checkin in

listFriends = a list of friend's id to checkin with

```
-(void)publishToFacebook:(NSString *)message
{
// Create the parameters dictionary that will keep the data that will be posted.
NSMutableArray *fArray = [NSMutableArray new];
for (RCPerson *person in listFriends)
{
    [fArray addObject:person.ID];
}

NSMutableDictionary * params = [NSMutableDictionary new];

if(fArray.count > 0)
{
    params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: message, @"message",[fArray componentsJoinedByString:@","], @"tags",  _place.facebookId, @"place", nil];

}
else
{
    params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: message, @"message", _place.facebookId, @"place", nil];

}

NSLog(@"params %@", params);
FBRequest *postRequest = [FBRequest requestWithGraphPath:@"me/feed" parameters:params HTTPMethod:@"POST"];
postRequest.session = FBSession.activeSession;
if(![postRequest.session.permissions containsObject:@"publish_stream"])
{

    [postRequest.session requestNewPublishPermissions:@[@"publish_stream", @"publish_actions"] defaultAudience:FBSessionDefaultAudienceEveryone completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, NSError *error) {
        [postRequest startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"error %@", error.description);
            if(error)
            {
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) {
                    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Facebook error" message:[self parseError:error] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
                    [alert show];
                });
            }
            NSLog(@"%@", result);

            //[self checkinMe];

        }];
    }];
}
else
{
    [postRequest startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"error %@", error.description);
        if(error)
        {

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) {
                UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Facebook error" message:[self parseError:error] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
                [alert show];
            });
        }
        NSLog(@"%@", result);
        //[self checkinMe];

    }];
}

}
```

Comment: from where I can get PlaceID?

Comment: But for this you have to have the facebook page id of the place

Comment: @nerowolfe can you please tell me how can i get place or page id?

Comment: For example with the help of this Facebook sdk method:         FBRequest *postLocRequest = [FBRequest requestForPlacesSearchAtCoordinate:currentLocation radiusInMeters:1000 resultsLimit:100 searchText:@"restaurant"];

Answer (score 1):

So first off, according to the Facebook API docs, the action you are trying to perform is deprecated.

You can read about it [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/checkin).

Now, you use /{user-id}/feed, and just add a location ID. Read the docs for this action [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/feed).

As for filtering, Not sure how that is a problem. Just filter the list of locations you show the user however you want and make sure to only pass one of those locations as the `place`.

Answer (score 0):

Publishing with `/checkin` is now deprecated. Check out the documentation - [`/checkin`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/checkin#publishing)

You have to use Open Graph Actions to do the same, here is the discussion on same: [facebbok sdk Integrate interactive map in a post like Foursquare](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22706323/facebbok-sdk-integrate-interactive-map-in-a-post-like-foursquare)